# A suitable pattern instead of returning nulls

Tags: java, design-patterns, optimization

What would be a good pattern to use here?

I don´t want to return nulls, that just does not feel right.

**Another thing is, what if I want to return the reason that causes it to null?  If caller knows why it is null, it can do some extra things so I want caller knows it and acts that way**

```
Public CustomerDetails getCustomerDetails(){
   if(noCustomer){    
     ..log..etc..
     return null;
   }

   if(some other bad weird condition){    
     ..log..etc..
     return null;
   }

   CustomerDetails details= getCustomerDetailsFromSomewhere();

   if (details!=null){
      return details;
   }
   else {
     ..log..etc..
     return null;
   }

}
```

Comment: why do you think returning null is bad ?? any specific reason ?

Comment: One possibility is, you can throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. Or create your own CustomException, and use it. But, trust me, that will take more of your time than returning null. Now why you don't want to return null?

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR I will do a null check everytime I have to call it so prone to errors, but main reason is it just "feels" wrong in this case. I might be wrong

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that the `null` does not explain its state, you can wrapper `CustomerDetails` with another class that can give more details. For example:

```
class Feedback()
{
    private CustomerDetails result;
    private int status;

    public static final int STATUS_OK = 0;
    public static final int STATUS_NULL = 1;
    public static final int STATUS_NO_CUSTOMER = 2;
    public static final int STATUS_BAD_CONDITION = 3;

    public Feedback(CustomerDetails result, int status)
    {
        this.result = result;
        this.status= status;
    }

    public CustomerDetails getResult(){return result;}
    public int getStatus(){return status;}
}
```

and change your method with:

```
Public Feedback getCustomerDetails()
{
   if(noCustomer)
   {
       ..log..etc..
       return new Feedback(null, Feeback.STATUS_NO_CUSTOMER);
   }

   if(some other bad weird condition)
   {
       ..log..etc..
       return new Feedback(null, Feeback.STATUS_BAD_CONDITION);
   }

   CustomerDetails details = getCustomerDetailsFromSomewhere();

   if(details != null)
   {
        return new Feedback(details, Feeback.STATUS_OK);
   }
   else
   {
       ..log..etc..
       return new Feedback(null, Feeback.STATUS_NULL);
   }
}
```

Then you can get the status by `feedback.getStatus()`.

Comment: I think there is a small mistake, you return details instaed of a Feedback object after null check

Comment: and could you compare this approach by just throwing a custom exception? that somehow looks simpler to me

Comment: @Spring By throwing an exception, the caller can only know the reason of the exception as a `String`. But with a feedback object, the caller can know the exact reason by an `int` and handle it in a better way (e.g in switch block) than parsing the String to know the reason. However, both mechanisms are correct and you can choose the one that satisfied your need.

Comment: @Spring In case you throw different exceptions instead of throwing the same exception everytime, then the caller can know the exact reason by having multiple catch statements.

Comment: actually I will use this for Rest jersey, depending on what went wrong or right I want to return the correct http code and throw necessary exception, bu wanna decouple this class from rest calls

Answer (score 8):

I think you have 3 main options:

- If null is a valid state I see no problem in returning null
- If null is an invalid state you should throw an exception
- Or make use of the [Null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)

If you are using googles [Guava libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) you can also use the [Optional](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) class.

Answer (score 3):

The more natural way in Java is to throw an exception on an error condition.

```
public CustomerDetails getCustomerDetails(){
   if(noCustomer){    
     ..log..etc..
     throw new NoSuchCustomer(customerName);
   }

   if(some other bad weird condition){    
     ..log..etc..
     throw new IllegalStateException("some other bad weird condition occurred");
   }

   CustomerDetails details= getCustomerDetailsFromSomewhere();

   if (details==null)
      throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to get customer details for "+ customerName);

   return details;
}
```

The method `getCustomerDetailsFromSomewhere()` could throw an exception instead of returning null.

Comment: tnx, could you tell what is the pros and cons of this approach instead of using null object design pattern or use a Feedback wrapper class

Comment: @Spring: exceptions are used to signal exceptional, non expected situations. If having no customer is a normal situation, returning null or an Optional is fine. On the contrary, if having no customer, or having this "bad weird" condition, is not expected, then an exception could be thrown. If you wrote the contract of the method, and describe what "noCustomer" and "bad weird condition" actually are, we could give you a better advice.

Comment: @JB Nizet those are user is loggedin in  and is user auhorized  checks, and I need to return a proper http code to the caller class cause it will be used by Jersey rest service and there are many other similar of these methods and I want to decouple this service methods from all rest related classes,

Comment: @JB Nizet in this case writing a wrapper feedback class(as Eng.Fouad sugegsted) which handles these situations by returning an appropriate web exception I think is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Try Guava's Optional.  See [this article](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained) on avoiding null.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Google Guava Optional](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html).

This will help.

> Many of the cases where programmers use null is to indicate some sort
>   of absence: perhaps where there might have been a value, there is
>   none, or one could not be found. For example, Map.get returns null
>   when no value is found for a key.
>
> Optional is a way of replacing a nullable T reference with a
>   non-null value. An Optional may either contain a non-null T reference
>   (in which case we say the reference is "present"), or it may contain
>   nothing (in which case we say the reference is "absent"). It is never
>   said to "contain null."

```
Optional<Integer> possible = Optional.of(5);
possible.isPresent(); // returns true
possible.get(); // returns 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try;

```
CustomerDetails details = setDetailsToEmpty();
```

or some equivalent.

You still have to check, either for null or empty customer details.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want null create a special CustomerDetails object

```
...
        public static final CustomerDetails EMPTY_CUSTOMER_DETAILS = new CustomerDetails();
...    
        public CustomerDetails getCustomerDetails(){
            ...
            if (details!=null){
                return details;
            }
            ...
            return EMPTY_CUSTOMER_DETAILS;
```